# How can I check if a frame exists and - if so - destroy it?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to pull some lines of text from a txt file online and show them in a window. So far, so good.

I want to reload/refresh that window every 'x' seconds so that the labels in it are redrawn (in case I've added, subtracted or changed the lines of text in that txt file), but couldn't do it so far.

I have added a Frame to the root and dynamically added the Labels to the Frame.
Every 'x' seconds, I want to check if that frame exists and - if so - destroy it, pull the content of the txt file again and recreate the frame and labels so that my labels are up to date.

For that, I've tried adding a 'Try/Except' at the begining of my function to check if the frame exists and destroy it, but I couldn't get it to work.

Any ideas that can help a very inexperienced python enthusiast?

```
#coding:utf-8

from Tkinter import *
import urllib
import time

mroot = Tk()

def mactions():
    mconteudo = urllib.urlopen('http://www.xyz.com.br/recados.txt')
    mtexto = mconteudo.read().split('***')

    #this is where I think I'm doing something wrong - I always get a NameError.
    try:
        mframe.destroy()
    except NameError:
        print '- NameError -'
    except UnboundLocalError:
        print '- UnboundLocalError -'

    mframe = Frame(mroot)
    for i in mtexto:
        w = Label(mframe, text=i)
        w.pack()
        wseparador = Label(mframe, text='________')
        wseparador.pack()
        mframe.pack()

    mroot.after(2000, mactions)

mactions()
mroot.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry AnojiRox, I changed my approach to the problem and worked around it. I can't tell if any of these solutions work.

Answer (score 0):

mframe is only defined within the function. it gets destroyed automatically after every pass of the function. To verify this you could add: "global mframe" to make it a global variable that lives until the next call of the function.

There are better solutions like storing the variable in a class as suggested in the other answer.

What about updating the label context? Also you might try to use only a single multiline label.

Comment: NEVER USE GLOBALS IN PYTHON! they hog unwanted memory.

Comment: As I wrote there are better solutions. But this answer helps him understand the problem.

Comment: He said he was a 'python inthusiast', thus he will be very enthusiastic about classes

Comment: @AnojiRox: _all_ variables use memory. And if you're using a global variable it doesn't hog unwanted memory by it's very definition (it can't be unwanted if you want to use the variable...). There are reasons for not using global variables, but "hog[ing] unwanted memory" isn't one of them.